# Converting to Double from String causing crash in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, parsing, type-conversion, nsnumberformatter

I'm trying to convert a textfield's text, which can be only numbers because of decimal number pad keyboard.

The variable I'm working with:

```
static var selectedMoneyMissing: Double = 30.0

let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
formatter.roundingMode = .down

let roundedReplacing = formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: Double(textField.text!.replacingOccurrences(of: ",", with: "."))!))

let roundedReplacingSecond = roundedReplacing.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "")
print(roundedReplacing)
print(roundedReplacingSecond)

FiltersViewController.selectedMoneyMissing = Double(roundedReplacingSecond)!
```

I'm getting "unexpectedly found nil...." error:

[image: screenshot]

This error occurs only when I'm putting value >= 1000. So I thought it could be because of the whitespace which is the reason why the roundedReplacingSecond variable exists. But it still does not work (actually, I don't know why the console is printing the variable "roundedReplacingSecond" with whitespace?).

Comment: Also, it is an incorrect assumption that your text field contains only digits due to the keyboard type. The user can paste anything into it.

Comment: Thank you @Paulw11 for pointing at this paste issue, I've fixed that.

Comment: Does the issue still persist in latest versions of Swift? Because I feel like it should only return nil instead of crashing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should configure your `NumberFormatter` more restrictive, especially by forbidding the use of a grouping and thousand separator:

```
formatter.groupingSeparator = false
formatter.hasThousandSeparator = false
```

See the documentation for even more properties. Then it shouldn't be necessary to do the text replacements at all, which may break depending on the users locale.

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer, I have resolved this issue by adding formatter.groupingSeparator = ""